# how to convert generated data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
         df = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=9, n_classes=1, random_state = 18,
                                     class_sep=2, n_informative=4)
```

after creating the data. it is tuple and after converting tuple into pandas dataframe

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"])
```

so i got 9 features (columns) but when i try to insert 9 cols it says.

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 9)

Basically i wanna generate data and convert it into pandas dataframe but could not get to it.
error is:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first entry of the tuple contains the feature data and the the second entry contains the class labels. So if you want to make a `pd.dataframe` of the feature data you should use `pd.DataFrame(df[0], columns=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"])`.

Answer (score 1):

The `make_classification` returns a tuple with two NumPy arrays. Just use the first result of the tuple result.

Have a look at the return type in the [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) documentation.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(df[0])
```

result:

```
             0         1         2  ...         6         7         8
0     1.223113 -1.962002 -0.288322  ... -2.152126  1.563291  2.790191
1    -0.239416 -3.782512 -1.587514  ... -0.519075  1.218147 -0.543413
2    -1.275076 -1.354999 -1.030673  ... -0.866303  1.915653  2.526826
3    -0.516765 -2.098868 -1.034506  ...  0.470277  1.917153  0.849975
4    -0.893197 -2.489030  1.012410  ...  3.562431  2.806255 -2.825570
...        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
9995 -1.665167 -1.106121 -0.381195  ...  0.543236  2.406625  2.216029
9996 -0.783265 -1.405607  0.257606  ... -0.251951  2.167685  2.461260
9997  2.341676 -3.382589 -0.120150  ...  0.066099  2.453412 -0.758382
9998 -0.662257 -1.531187 -0.709562  ...  0.156203  2.495238  2.452315
9999 -0.756892 -4.895147 -0.385215  ...  0.898117  2.624591 -2.188389
```

Plus: There is a mismatch between the import and the usage:

```
!!! from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
!!! df = make_classification(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=9, n_classes=1, random_state = 18, class_sep=2, n_informative=4)
```

This line returns a tuple in which the first entry has Feature values or 'X' and the second entry has target values.

So, to make it a pandas data frame you have to make slice it like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0], columns=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"])
```

Full Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import pandas as pd

df = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=9, n_classes=1, random_state = 18,
                                     class_sep=2, n_informative=4)

df = pd.DataFrame(df[0], columns=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"])
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]